# What is $L_5$ and why is it 11?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

What is $L_5$ and why is it $11$? I have seen this in the mathematical watch that $11$ is presented by $L_5$. I am attaching an image so that you can understand more specifically what I am asking I first thought its Laplace transformation of $5$ but I think it is not true because Laplace will convert it to function $5/s$.

The sequence of Lucas numbers is:

```
 2,1,3,4,7,11
```

so it is Lucas number $L_5$

Comment: Google it up. Lucas sequence and Fibonacci sequence both share the property that the next number is the sum of the previous two.

Comment: Also, I recommend that you study [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Answer (score 1):

The $n$th Lucas Number $L_n$ is defined recursively as $L_n=L_{n-1}+L_{n-2}$, where $L_1=2$ and $L_2=1$. In the case of $L_5$, we can see that $L_5=L_4+L_3=7+4=11$. Generally, sequences that are defined recursively such that each term is the sum of the previous two terms are referred to as $f$-sequences. The most famous example is the Fibonacci Sequence, where the first and second terms are defined to be both $1$.